# How to Encode and Decode password in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

In my project there is "forgot password functionality". When user do forgot password then email should go to user mail Id with decoded password. after he logins in then login functionality should be worked.

I have used the following encoders.

```
Secuirty.yml:
    security:
        encoders:
            Coupon\EntityBundle\Entity\SupportUsers:
                algorithm: sha1
                encode_as_base64: false
                iterations: 1

    #    encoders:
    #        Coupon\EntityBundle\Entity\SupportUsers: plaintext

        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

        providers:
            main:
                entity:
                    class: Coupon\EntityBundle\Entity\SupportUsers
                    property: supportUserUsername

        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false

            login:
                pattern:  ^/login$
                security: false

            coupon_login_forgot_password:
                pattern:  ^/forgot-password$
                security: false

    #        coupon_report_categoryWiseCSV:
    #            pattern:  ^/report/csv-category$
    #            security: false

    #        default_security_target:
    #            pattern:  ^/users/home$
    #            security: false

            coupon_dashboard:
                pattern:    ^/
                form_login:
                    check_path: login_check
                    login_path: login
                    default_target_path: coupon_dashboard
                    always_use_default_target_path: true
                logout:
                    path:   logout
                    target: login
                remember_me:
                    key: trex-kharadi6
                    lifetime: 43200
                    always_remember_me: false
                    remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
                    path: ~
                    domain: ~
                #anonymous: ~
                #http_basic:
                #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/coupon_dashboard, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
```

How to write custom encode and decode methods and how to configure it.

Forgot password Action:
    Here, I am retrieving the encoded password from database.

```
public function forgotPasswordAction(Request $request) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $username = $request->get('username');
            $couponHelper = $this->get('coupon_helper');

            if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {


                //echo $username; die;
                if ($username == '') {
                    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('msg', $this->get('translator')->trans('forgot.pwd.enter'));
                } else {
                    $user = $em->getRepository('CouponEntityBundle:SupportUsers')->findBy(array('supportUserUsername' => trim($username), 'supportUserStatus' => '0'));
                    if (count($user) != 0) {
                        $password = $user[0]->getSupportUserPassword();
                        $email = $user[0]->getSupportUserEmail();
                        if ($email != '') {

                            //emailer helper.
                            $data['firstName']='';
                            $data['lastName']='';
                            $data['userName'] = $user[0]->getSupportUserUsername()?$user[0]->getSupportUserUsername():'';                      
                            $data['email'] = $email;
                            $data['password'] = $password ? $password:'';
                            $data['instance'] = 'forgotpassword';
                            $emailStatus = $couponHelper->emailer($data);
                            $logger = $this->get('logger');
                            $logger->info('[Email]: [' . $emailStatus . ']');
                            unset($data);

                            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('msg', $this->get('translator')->trans('forgot.pwd.sent'));
                        } else {
                            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $this->get('translator')->trans('forgot.pwd.reg.not.email'));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $this->get('translator')->trans('forgot.pwd.not.reg'));
                    }
                }

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('coupon_login_forgot_password'));
            }

            return $this->render('CouponLoginBundle:Login:forgot_password.html.twig', array('username' => $username));
        }
```

So, in forgot password action how to get original password and mail it the user. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You should never be able to decrypt a user's password and should definitely never email it to them.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T do this. It's a security concern, you never should able to decode the passwords of your users.

The password in fact is memorized as an hash, it's a one-way process that can't be played backwards, purposefully.

Comment: Then how should I do this. Can you please provide me custom password encode and decode function and configuration???

Comment: You should use the standard process, that sends a mail to the user and resets the password, asking for a new one.

Comment: In symfony, there is no any interface to generate custom password??

Comment: No. You can get done using external bundles, like FOS (FriendsOfSymfony)